# How to add active class to a list of buttons onClick, they are not controlled by parent

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a chatbox component like the facebook-status post. There are buttons on the bottom. When a user clicks them I load various box styles. I need to set the class of current button "active".

My component is not controlled by a parent so I cannot set any prop bases solution. I know how to implement a ternary operator but don't know how can I use it here?

I have tried these solutions but these all are parent based.
 [React Js conditionally applying class attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533171/react-js-conditionally-applying-class-attributes)
[react change the class of list item on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427341/react-change-the-class-of-list-item-on-click)

```
import React from "react"
import StyleButton from "./StyleButton"

class Post extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            selectedClass: 'red',
            displayBtns: true,
            buttons: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
        }
    }

    handleDisplayBtnClick = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            displayBtns: !prevState.displayBtns 
        }))
    }

    handleChange = e => {
        let btnId = e.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        switch (btnId) {
            case '1':
                this.setState({selectedClass: "purple" })
                break;
            case '2':
                this.setState({selectedClass: "cyan" })
                break;
            case '3':
                this.setState({selectedClass: "ballons" })
                break;
            case '4':
                this.setState({selectedClass: "clouds" })
                break;
            case '5':
                this.setState({selectedClass: "thumbs" })
                break;
            case '6':
                this.setState({selectedClass: "smile" })
                break;
            default: 
                this.setState({selectedClass: "default" })
          }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className={`bg container ${this.state.selectedClass}`} >
                <input className="input" placeholder="What's on your mind?" type="text"/>
                <button className={this.state.displayBtns ? 'closeBtn' : 'openBtn'} onClick={this.handleDisplayBtnClick}>&nbsp;</button>

                { this.state.displayBtns ? 
                    <div className="btns" >
                        {this.state.buttons.map(eachButtonNumber => 
                            <button 
                                key={eachButtonNumber} 
                                data-id={eachButtonNumber} 
                                onClick={this.handleChange}
                            >&nbsp;</button>
                        )}
                    </div> 
                : null }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Post
```

I want to add an "active" class when I click it on the buttons which are rendered from "buttons.map". Right now my buttons is changing the Div class to change the background.

```
<button 
key={eachButtonNumber} 
data-id={eachButtonNumber} 
onClick={this.handleChange} >&nbsp;</button>
```

Also, want to know If this is the right way of doing it?

Posted the whole code and GIF at "https://github.com/ankursehdev/facebook-post-box-reactjs"

My Rendered HTML - I want "active" on the list of buttons.

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="bg container smile">
    <input class="input" placeholder="What's on your mind?" type="text">
    <button class="closeBtn">&nbsp;</button>
    <div class="btns">
        <button data-id="1">&nbsp;</button>
        <button data-id="2">&nbsp;</button>
        <button data-id="3">&nbsp;</button>
        <button data-id="4">&nbsp;</button>
        <button data-id="5">&nbsp;</button>
        <button data-id="6">&nbsp;</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your buttons have a little more detail to them this is pretty easy. If instead of `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` for your buttons, if the array had an object for each button, each button could have properties that can be matched to the state. So maybe like this:

```
[
  {id: 1, buttonName: 'purple'},
  {id: 2, buttonName: 'cyan'},
  {id: 3, buttonName: 'ballons'},
  {id: 4, buttonName: 'clouds'},
  {id: 5, buttonName: 'thumbs'},
  {id: 6, buttonName: 'smile'},
]
```

Then in your `map` loop, each button is checking if the `selectedClass` state matches its `buttonName` property and adding an `active` class in that case. Note you will need to point to `id` property now for the numeric id of each button.

```
{this.state.buttons.map(eachButtonNumber => 
  <button
    className={this.state.selectedClass === eachButtonNumber.buttonName && 'active'}
    key={eachButtonNumber.id} 
    data-id={eachButtonNumber.id} 
    onClick={this.handleChange}
  >
    &nbsp;
  </button>
)}
```

Comment: Yes, I have full control over that array. And do you think this is the right approach to write React app in general? I mean the full application. and Thanks

Comment: It's the most React-y way to manage conditional classes in a loop that I know of. Happy to help!

Comment: I am getting a warning after using this: So I am using the ternary operator. 

Following is the warning. 

> Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `className`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: className="false" or className={value.toString()}.

If you used to conditionally omit it with className={condition && value}, pass className={condition ? value : undefined} instead.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this is to get the className to be applied inside the render before returning the jsx.

Like in render you can write the condition as below

```
let classNameStyle = "" 
if(this.state.displayBtns)
   classNameStyle = 'closeBtn '
else
   classNameStyle = 'openBtn '

if(this.state.active)
   classNameStyle = classNameStyle + 'active'
```

Now apply this classNameStyle value to className property of button.
(Note ) See the space in assignment of first className

Comment: Hello Raj, I am trying to apply active class to ``` <button 
                                key={eachButtonNumber} 
                                data-id={eachButtonNumber} 
                                onClick={this.handleChange}
                            >&nbsp;</button>  not the openBtn and CloseBtn. There is a list of buttons from the buttons.map.